# Filter using accepted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, filtering

There is an option to view list of questions that we have answered in **Answers** tab in profile.  In that we can filter them based on

**votes, activity and newest**

> [image]

Is there any plan to view the *list of answers that were ACCEPTED?*  Something like this in UI below

> [image]

Not sure whether this is a duplicate question, it would bee great to have such an option here.

**Updates:**

Based on @hims056's answer, I can understand that accepted answers can be filtered too like

[image]

Not sure, may this be a reason for not shown in UI?  *However if so we can have a tab like I said and redirect it.*

I don't know what are the disadvantage it will have.  Just wanted to share with you.

Comment: 2 downvotes.  Is this a bad request?

Comment: then there should be one that says unaccepted as well. Why would anyone want to go to someones profile to see questions with (un) accepted answers?

Comment: @Michael I wanted to know how many answers I have given that has been accepted?  I didn't asked to view other profiles.  I think that is not wrong?

Comment: If you go to your profile and to your answers, you can already see which one have an accepted answer and which one has not. When a question has an accepted answer you see it has a yellow color in it.

Comment: @Michael you're not getting my point.  I know that I can see the accepted answer marked in some color.  But it would be cool to filter only the list of accepted answers that where my point is.  Hope you got my point.

Comment: That will most likely lead into a lot of useless discussion when someone changes his accepted answer. Already now people are demanding to accept answers within a couple of minutes.

Comment: In any case, accepted answer only say that something working for the questioner at that time. It doesn't have any other purpose than that (other than rep++) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by our advanced search feature:

```
user:<UserId> isaccepted:yes
```

or

```
user:me isaccepted:yes
```

E.g.

[user:1671639 isaccepted:yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1369235%20isaccepted:yes)

or

[user:me isaccepted:yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20isaccepted:yes)

Comment: Oh, this is good.  However it would good to have it in UI.  Is there any plan going on?

Comment: @user1671639 - Not sure about the UI plan. But if you think it's a good to have UI for that, you may keep feature-request.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Advance search tip.. like this  [user:me isaccepted:yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20isaccepted:yes).. for now

Although i must agree, adding filter section in there will certainly help, its good for UI as well...